# What should I import for GLKVector2 in Swift?

Tags: ios, math, swift

I have the follow code:

```
func CGPointFromGLKVector2(vector : GLKVector2) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPointMake(vector.x, vector.y)
}
```

The error message is:

> Use of undeclared type 'CGPoint'

After I *import SpriteKit*, I got:

> Use of module 'GLKVector2' as a type

What should I do next? I can't find any related information in document. Thanks

**NOTE:**

I actually want to covert the following function C(objC) code into Swift:

```
static __inline__ CGPoint CGPointFromGLKVector2(GLKVector2 vector) {
    return CGPointMake(vector.x, vector.y);
}
```

Comment: GLKVector2 is part of GLKit

Comment: But import GLKit doesn't help.